# post android simple app

Tags: android, post

I need a simple androd application, which POST a word to the server and recive the answer from server. I creat a form, which have two line and one button. In first line user write the word and click the button. In this time the app send this word to the server. When server send back response we show this respons in other line.

I right some code but this code don`t work on android 23. I also try to do this with retrofit, but I have varios problem with understending of this fiture.

I know that just need use POST, but don`t know how.

And can I send the ip adress of my android to the server?

Comment: share the code, what have you tried

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/UC-eEoo4ta3hV

it`s a java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:
It will also return the response from that page as a String

```
public static String postRequest(String post_url, String data) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(post_url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            if (200 <= connection.getResponseCode() && connection.getResponseCode() <= 299) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
            } else {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
            }

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And call it by:

```
postRequest("http://your-url", "name=value&anothername=somevalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think volley will fit your needs, it's a very simple library that can handle asynchronous requests :

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

"And can I send the ip adress of my android to the server?"

Sure, to get your android ip just use a code like this on server side, assuming you're using PHP :

```
<?
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
    echo "<br />Your IP is : $ip"; 
?>
```

EDIT : NodsJS example

```
app.post('/getip', function (req, res) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
         req.connection.remoteAddress || 
         req.socket.remoteAddress ||
         req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
})
```

Comment: thanks for the link. 
I need use the node.js server, if you have some links with information how work with ip on node.js, I would very grateful.